# Calling window.open JavaScript in WebView

Tags: c#, webview, uwp, window.open

I have a `WebView` in an UWP app. The page shows a popup window by calling `window.open` (https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp). Is there a way for me to make this open in the `WebView`?

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way for me to make this open in the WebView?

The `open()` method creates a new secondary browser window. If you want the new page to open also inside the `WebView` means that you don't want to create a new secondary browser window but navigate to another page in current window.

In that case, you could use  `window.location` instead of `window.open`. For example:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function open_win() {
            //window.open("http://www.microsoft.com")
            window.location = "http://www.microsoft.com"
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <form>
        <input type=button value="navigate to" onclick="open_win()">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I do not have control over the website source code.

Comment: @Ham.Abdu2, in that case, you may have no way to do this. `Windows.open'  create in another window, but `WebView` it self is just one. What you are wanting is to change the server side feature.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to assume that you want to navigate to another page in the current window, instead of a popup. Here is something that should be helpful. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/web-view#navigating-to-content